# New socket for client to send file to server

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a client that sends a file to the server and sends other values to the server.I managed to transfer the file but it is not opened until i close the socket.So i made another socket in the client side just for sending the file,but the server read it as if it is another client and incremented the clients number and gave me an exception as well saying> Socketexception:software caused connection abort: socket write error.Here is the code of client side with a new socket just for the sending,Can anyone help me about that?Thanks in advance.

```
try
{
    Socket sendSock=new Socket("localhost", 8080);
    outC.println("AcceptFile,");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(p);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(buffer);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sendSock.getOutputStream()) ;
    oos.writeObject(buffer);
    sendSock.close();
}
catch(Exception c)
{
    System.err.println("exc" + c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - Don't make a new socket. Just wrap the output stream and send the objects over.

Assuming outC is also a connection to your server, do this

```
outC.println("AcceptFile,");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(p);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(buffer);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(originalSocket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(buffer);
```

This will write an object to the underlying stream.

Now on the server side, you can do this

```
if(clientMessage.equals("AcceptFile,")) {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    byte[] buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();
    // do what you will with that
}
```

Comment: @glowcoder Thank you for your post,but i used this code before and it transfered the file correctly but the file is not opened unless i close the socket,that is my problem.

Comment: @Fatema What do you mean by "the file is not opened"? You're sending a `byte[]` over the socket. I'm expecting that you're going to write that `byte[]` to a file and work with it that way (or just work with the `byte[]` as it is.) Could you elaborate on what you mean by "file is not opened?"

Comment: @glowcoder I mean that the file is created for example (source.pdf) but when i try to open it while the server-client application is still running, the pdf reader program displays a message saying couldn`t read the file.But when i close the application and try to open the file,it is read correctly.

Comment: @Faterna Mohsen so you haven't closed the file. So close it.

Comment: @Fatema I agree with EJP. that sounds completely unrelated to whether or not the bytes are making it across. Flush and close the file you've written.

Comment: @EJP @glowcoder really i don`t know what to say:) i have forgotten to close the file and flush! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem in supporting multiple connections is on the server side.  I don't see how you are going to solve that server behavior from the client side.  It doesn't support multiple connections in one session.

Comment: I just thought of that solution because i found that i need to close the socket after writing the file.